# Reversing a jquery by selecting siblings

Tags: jquery, show-hide, dokuwiki

This is to customize dokuwiki, I have this code (https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:clicknshow) that I want to "reverse".  So that clicking on a heading will close all other headings, making for a cleaner printjob.

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').css('cursor','pointer').click(function(){
    var tag=this.tagName, 
        tagIdx=parseInt(tag.match(/\d/)[0],10), 
        clicknshow=jQuery(this).data('clicknshow') || false,
        fname=clicknshow?'show':'hide';

    jQuery(this).data('clicknshow',!clicknshow).nextAll().each(function(){
        var jqNode=jQuery(this);
        if (jqNode.is(':header')){
          var hIdx=parseInt(this.tagName.match(/\d/)[0],10);
          if (hIdx<=tagIdx) { return false; }
          jqNode.data('clicknshow',!clicknshow);
        }
        jqNode[fname]();
    });
  });
});
```

After a day of trying I need to just realize that I don't know jscript at all, and I need help.
You can edit a section of working code here.
http://jsfiddle.net/W35ny/

Comment: Why don't you use toggle function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/hcwUX/):

```
$("h3").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings("div").hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

to your second question [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/k47US/)(show all of them if click again):

```
$("h3").click(function(){

    if($(this)[0].getAttribute("DivShown")== "true")
    {
        $(this).siblings("div").show();
        $(this)[0].setAttribute("DivShown","false");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).siblings("div").hide();
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this)[0].setAttribute("DivShown","true");
    }
});
```

*this code looks pretty awful, just a tricky way to solve this.

this specifically works for the order of your html elements
(all `<h3>` and `<div>` are brothers and all `<div>` are text to a `<h3>`)
so you hide all brother `<div>` then show the next one to the current `<h3>`

Comment: Love this, anyway to click again and expand all headings?

Comment: oh,come on, try it by yourself, just ask if the `<div>` next to the current `<h3>` is visible then show them all(i will try it anyway).

Comment: I'll see what I can do. :)

Comment: I would like to say I learned something, but I doubt I'll remember how I got this working. 

http://jsfiddle.net/CKSEH/

Comment: @user2461352: with practice you will remember, and you must remember to choose an answer.

Comment: Well it isn't working in dokuwiki, so i will have to see how or why that is different.  Thanks though for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $("h3[class^=sectionedit]").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
        var isVisible = $(this).next(".level3").is(":visible");
        $("h3[class^=sectionedit]").next(".level3").hide();
        (isVisible) ? $(this).next(".level3").hide() : $(this).next(".level3").show();
    });
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/f4Rmq/)

Comment: That is pretty close to just want I was looking for.  After commenting out the lower bit. (demo) just needs to not hide everything and keep selection open on first click.

Comment: No, that is the same functionality as it originally had.